Trailing 12 months SUM for each customer
I have a table  Sales with the following columns -



Emp ID
Activity Date
Sales




1234
2024-01-01
254.22


1234
2024-05-08
227.10


5678
2023-02-01
254.22


5678
2024-05-01
227.10



I need to find the total trailing 12 months sales of each employee. Not every employee has a sale on each activity date.
The end goal is to answer business questions like - For all employees active in Jan 2024, what was the trailing 12 months sales for them?



Emp ID
Activity Date
Sales




1234
2024-01-01
254.22


1234
2024-05-08
227.10


5678
2023-02-01
254.22


5678
2024-05-01
227.10



From Sales table, I tried to first do a cross join with a calendar dimension table, but that is not the result I expected. The approach I was thinking was too have all calendar dates, and all employee IDs with sales (0 is no sales for that employee for that date), and then do a partition by empID for rows preceding.
select CAL.*, S.emp_id, S.ACTIVITY_DAte, S.Sales
from sales s
cross join CAL

Please provide the proper output that is required.
